# Excel VBA Need to Set a Filter Criteria From the Particular Range

Tags: excel, vba

Need to Set a Filter Criteria From the Particular Range
Showing Error as Run-Time error '13':Type Mismatch
Using filters need to select Words like "India","UK","USA" and More those words are stored in particular Range (Bj1 to Bj & IWRange1)

```
IWRange1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WorkingClient").Range("Bj" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
         Dim strName As String
         arMyArray = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WorkingClient").Range("Bj1" & ":" & "Bj" & IWRange1)

     find_IW = WorksheetFunction.Match(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WorkingClient").Range("A15"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PF Working").Range("a7:zz7"), 0)
    erRange12 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(find_IW, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WorkingClient").Range("AZ:BB"), 3, 0)


ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PF Working").Range(erRange12 & "8" & ":" & erRange12 & IWEnd).AutoFilter Field:=find_IW, Criteria1:=Array(arMyArray, "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not working".  Error message? If so, what and on what line.  Excel crashes?  Computer crashes? Unexpected results? etc. Also, please provide sufficient information so we can reproduce your problem.  We have no idea what your data looks like.

Comment: Error Message is Run-Time Error '1004': Autofilter method of range class failed

Comment: I Want to Filter a data and need  get specific  words and that words are in a given range

Comment: Please post more of your code for us to understand. Also, you seem to be using different character for **double quotes**. One has a ascii code of 34 and the other i suspect has the ascii code 253

Comment: Possibly because you are using strange characters for your `Criteria1` and `Criteria2` arguments.   `"`, `“` and `”` are not interchangeable.

Comment: You are not selecting values from the 2D array `arMyArray ` If you are using loop like `for i = LBound(arMyArray, 1) to UBound(arMyArray, 1)` to filter different fields, then you can select value by `arMyArray(i,1)`

Comment: Hi @Zac Added some code pls refer

Comment: What the value of `find_IW`?